# C++ 2d array index error

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I have a question regarding 2d array index. Here player_board is declared as a double pointer to char, which is a 2d array. Then I allocate the memory and everything seems to work just fine. x_vals and y_vals are two vectors that store x coordinates and y coordinates. I am trying to replace the original value of given x, y value with 'A'. When I print out the element of x_vals and y_vals it seems fine but when I use them as index, they begin to begin randomly assign. Here is my code...How should I solve this? Thx for helping

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x_vals.size(); i++) {
    cout << x_vals.at(i) - 48 << y_vals.at(i) - 48 << endl;
    player_board[x_vals.at(i) - 48][y_vals.at(i) - 48] = 'A';
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the declaration/assignment statements for x_vals, y_vals, and player_board?

Comment: Could you also show as an example of the output to see if there's something wrong with the indices?

Comment: You need to post full, compilable (but minimal) code which reproduces your problem. That said, I strongly recommnd not playing array index russian roulette like in the code you posted.

Comment: The '-48' seems risky as you could be indexing the array by a negative number.

Comment: why do you '-48' at x_vals and y_val. What type of x_vals and y_vals vector (double or int) ?

Comment: If you mean `'0'`, write `'0'` and not `48`. According to your code, `x_vals` and `y_vals` don't store coordinates, they store digits (characters) that possibly represent coordinates. Storing the actual coordinates instead of digits (characters) would simplify your code and be less error-prone. (I suspect that you've missed a digit->number or number->digit conversion somewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming x_vals and y_vals are declared as vector of int or uint, thus when trying to obtain a cell at a certain index in a 2d dimentional matrix you might provide the matrix with negative values.
For example lets say your x_val.at(1) = 10 -> then you will try to access the cell at index -38.
Correct me if I'm wrong and kindly provide some more information about the types of x_vals and y_vals and the matrix allocation of player_board.

Answer (score 0):

When you print out values of x_vals.at(i) - 48 and y_vals.at(i) - 48, are you not getting some negative values? I think you are getting these negative values and then trying to access a value in an array at a negative index e.g. player_board[-10]...

Maybe you could try using the absolute values of x_vals.at(i) - 48 and y_vals.at(i) - 48 as you index values

Also are you sure when you use the index values they do not go outside the declared range of your array.